# Derivation of Product Rule for Finite Differences without Shift Operator

Tags: calculus, derivatives, finite-differences, discrete-calculus

Let $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$, and let the $\Delta$ be the forward difference operator on functions be
$$\Delta f := \frac{f_{j+1}-f_j}{\Delta x}$$
where $f_j = f(j\Delta x)$

Now I can derive the product rule for finite differences in terms of $\Delta f$ and $\Delta g$ easily

$$\Delta h = \frac{h_{j+1}-h_j}{\Delta x} = \frac{f_{j+1}g_{j+1}-f_jg_j}{\Delta x} = \frac{f_{j+1}g_{j+1}\color{red}{-f_jg_{j+1} }{\color{blue}{+f_jg_{j+1}}}-f_jg_j}{\Delta x}=g_{j+1}\Delta f+f_j\Delta g$$

However, you can see in the first term that $g$ is shifted forward by $1$ step.

But on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Rules_for_calculus_of_finite_difference_operators) for the finite differences the rule is express with a second order term:

$$\Delta(fg) = f\Delta g + g \Delta f + \Delta f \Delta g$$

I have tried converting my expression to this with all sorts of algebra, and I even tried using the wiki's formula to go backwards to my equation, but nothing has worked. It's clear there must be some clever trick to convert the shift operator in terms of $f,\Delta f,\Delta g$ but I can't see how.

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you keep delta x in denominator ? Wouldn't it always be one

Comment: @Buraian: if the assumption that $\Delta x=1$ is removed we would get the stated results.

Comment: @Buraian I dont think so because for finite approximations $f_{j+1}$ and $f_j$ differ by one spatial step in $j$, by the distance of the spatial step $\Delta x$ is dependent on the domain $x$ itself. If $0\le x\le 10$ and you partition it with $\Delta x = 0.01$, your spatial steps $j$ would be different that spatial steps with $\Delta x = 0.001$.

Comment: I think it's redundant, doing it like that just scales up each finite difference by 10^3 , doesn't add any new information to the problem @Hushus46

Comment: @Buraian While I get your point of view, its just the context I'm working with is defined this way, because it relates to solving PDE's with finite approximation.

Comment: Oh now it is more understandable :P I've removed my answer but check this playlist out if you are interested in finite difference calculus [see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBk14Y_ce_0&list=PLKc2XOQp0dMwj9zAXD5LlWpriIXIrGaNb&index=66)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $g_{j+1}\Delta f=(g_{j+1}-g_j)\Delta f+g_j\Delta f$, so this is the same as $g_j\Delta f+\Delta x\Delta g\Delta f$.

Comment: Note that in my definition $\Delta f$ has, by definition, denominator $\Delta x$. So I'm not sure how to use that here, since you write $g_{j+1}-g_j = \Delta g$ when my $\Delta g$ would be$\frac{g_{j+1}-g_j }{\Delta x}$

Comment: Good point.  I am considering the consequences of this notation...

Comment: @Hushus46: I believe the effective result is as I show, with an extra $\Delta x$ helping that last term.

Comment: I think you are correct